# How to change markdown code snippet background in JupyterLab?

Tags: python, markdown, jupyter, jupyter-lab

You can easily write markdown in a JupterLab cell by setting `Code > Markdown` like this:

[image]

But in my opinion the formatting is messed up. Code *lines* look fine. But code *blocks* are missing the grey background that we all, arguably, know and love on StackOverflow for example.

#### JupyterLab markdown cell in editing mode:

[image]

#### JupyterLab markdown cell after running it:

[image]

How can we change the settings so that the background for the code block is grey?

I've looked around under `Advanced Settings` for the `Markdown Viewer`, but to no avail.

Thank you for any suggestions!